# Multiple SED commands?

Tags: shell, unix, sed

How to do multiple sed commands? Can anyone give an example of the syntax?

For example, how would I combined these:

```
sed <SOMETHING> > file.txt
sed <SOMETHING_ELSE> > file.txt
```

..into:

```
sed <SOMETHING>,<SOMETHING_ELSE> > file.txt
```

Thanks for any help!

I'll clarify the question to give a real world example:

I have these 3 commands:

```
sed '/<!-- BEGIN DEVELOPMENT -->/,/<!-- END DEVELOPMENT -->/d'  > app/editor/index2.php
sed '/<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTION/d' app/editor/index.php > app/editor/index2.php
sed '/END PRODUCTION -->/d' app/editor/index.php > app/editor/index2.php
```

I need to run these 3 commands and produce 1 output file (index2.php) based on the original file (index.php)

Comment: what are those `SOMETHING/ELSE`s ?

Comment: What is the role of JavaScript here?

Comment: @undefined I'm sure there's a jQuery plugin for that. `=]`

Comment: @undefined I guess OP wants to do modification on js files..  and the js used jquery lib. :)

Comment: Your example _doesn't_ do two different transforms to the same file, which I assume is what you want -- instead, it runs one sed transform (reading from stdin), writing to a file, and then truncates and overwrites that file's contents with the output from a separate sed invocation, completely discarding the first invocation.

Comment: try to hit `info sed` , there are some fully working samples.

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific

Comment: Don't do that. sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single file, for anything else just use awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave this example:

```
sed '/<!-- BEGIN DEVELOPMENT -->/,/<!-- END DEVELOPMENT -->/d' > app/editor/index2.php
sed '/<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTION/d' app/editor/index.php > app/editor/index2.php
sed '/END PRODUCTION -->/d' app/editor/index.php > app/editor/index2.php
```

I think what you're really trying to do is take a file "index.php" and remove any blocks between and including lines that contain`<!-- BEGIN DEVELOPMENT -->` and `/<!-- END DEVELOPMENT -->` and would remove any lines that contain either `<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTION` or `END PRODUCTION -->`.

If so, then in awk one way to write that is just:

```
/<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTION|END PRODUCTION -->/  { next }
/<!-- (BEGIN|END) DEVELOPMENT -->/ { skip = !skip; next }
!skip
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
abc
<!-- BEGIN DEVELOPMENT -->
def
<!-- END DEVELOPMENT -->
ghi
<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTION
klm
END PRODUCTION -->
nop
$
$ cat tst.awk
/<!-- BEGIN PRODUCTION|END PRODUCTION -->/  { next }
/<!-- (BEGIN|END) DEVELOPMENT -->/ { skip = !skip; next }
!skip
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
abc
ghi
klm
nop
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this has to do with javascript, but one way is to use the semicolon, like so:

```
sed 's/1/2/g;/^ *$/d' file > newfile
```

This is just an example that would replace all 1s with 2s and delete all blank links in `file` and write the output to `newfile`.

Comment: this depends on the `SOMETHING`, e.g. one is `/foo/p`, the other one is `/bar/p`, if he does with 2 sed cmds, the 1st will print lines have `foo`, 2nd cmd prints `bar`. if a line has both `foo and bar`, it will be printed separately (from two cmds). but if we make them in one sed, this `foo and bar` line would be printed twice in adjacent. the result is not exactly same as two seds. so `SOMETHING` does matter! also for those cmd like `3d` and `5d` when 2nd sed comes, the line number would be different. so the result is also different.

Comment: Correct, you'll need to apply these commands in the appropriate context. But, as everyone else, I don't really know what SOMETHING is, so I was just trying to be helpful and provide what I thought would be useful.